# How to make Mocha to check mutating object in real time?

Tags: testing, mocha.js, javascript-objects, chai

In the "test1", the property value `foo` of `testObject` already became to `bravo`.
Thus, both "test1" and "test2" will fail.

```js
import { assert as Assert } from "chai";

describe("test", (): void => {

  const testObject: { foo: string; } = { foo: "alpha" };

  it("test1", (): void => {
    Assert.deepEqual(testObject, { foo: "alpha" }); 
  });

  testObject.foo = "bravo";
  it("test2", (): void => {
    Assert.deepEqual(testObject, { foo: "bravo" });
  });
});
```

I need to solve this for testing of my function, which among it's functionality clones the array:

1. Create array
2. Deeply clone array
3. Check has array been cloned correctly
4. Mutate cloned array (will break step 3 tests)
5. Make sure that initial array was not changed

Comment: I would create a new independent instance of `testObject` in each test.

Answer (score 0):

Unit test cases should maintain good isolation, try not to share any test data between test cases. In addition, the results of each test case must be predictable.

If you share data between test cases, mutate data is likely to break other test cases. You may also need to execute tests in a certain order, but test runners are generally executed concurrently, so the order of execution of test cases is not guaranteed

A better solution is to prepare test data for each test case. For JavaScript Object, you should create a new copy for it.